# Iterating over integers and decimal values in for-loop python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am making Python code for finding the mann-whitney u stat for samples larger than 20.

In the process, if there are ties in the ranking of samples, the standard deviation formula for the ranks is as follows:

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test)

I particularly having trouble with the summation portion.

Here,  "t_i is the number of subjects sharing rank i, and k is the number of (distinct) ranks."

I have the following array of ranks:

`ranks = [  7.    8.   12.   11.    9.   10.    1.    3.    4.5   2.    6.    4.5]`

Now, I have written the following function to calculate the sigma portion of the equation:

```
sigma = 0
for i in range(1, np.amax(ranks)):
    num =  ranks.count(i)**3 - ranks.count(i)
    denom = (n1+n2)*((n1+n2)-1)
    sigma += num/denom
```

However, this is not correct, because when I'm summing from i to k, I'm looking at the integers. I'm not considering the ranks that are decimal values, such as 4.5.

How do I get around this?

Comment: didn't you forget something here: `denom = (n1+n2)((n1+n2)-1)` ? ;)

Comment: iterate over the *ranks*, not a range. I.e `for r in ranks:`

Comment: Oh, oops, you're right. Fixed the typo @alfasin +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like initially you were trying to loop over all integers in the range `[1, max(ranks)]` which is not what the sum is doing. The sum is iterating over each unique element in ranks and aggregating a certain transformation of that element.

Here is a more straightforward approach. Instead of dealing with indices I iterate over the elements themselves. t<sub>i</sub> will the ith element of the collection of *unique* elements of `rank`. Every element will be accounted for. It won't matter if they are integers or not:

```
for ti in set(ranks):
        num =  ranks.count(ti)**3 - ranks.count(ti)
        denom = (n1+n2)*((n1+n2)-1)
        sigma += num/denom
```

Comment: Your first example is good, but your second, not so much; `for i in range(len(someseq)):` is an anti-pattern for recidivist C programmers; it's slower and less Pythonic in every way.

Comment: I know but the question had me thinking in the integer index way :-(  I show both because I think you have to understand the index way to see how it is corresponding to the sum in the image.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski But, what if there are repeats in ranks, like for instance, I have two instances of "4.5." When I do ti in ranks, wouldn't it just count 4.5 twice?

Comment: @Jonathan correct. what would you want it doing? If you want unique values consider a `set`

Comment: Well, in the OP, I noted "t_i is the number of subjects sharing rank i," hence why I did ".count(i)"

Comment: @Jonathan actually now, forgot to put it in a set to iterate over distinct elems of rank